# Scrape Yahoo Finance Financial Ratios

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrap the value of the Current Ratio (as shown below) from Yahoo Finance using Beautiful Soup, but it keeps returning an empty value.

[image]

Interestingly, when I look at the Page Source of the URL, the value of the Current Ratio is not listed there.

My code so far is:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GSB/key-statistics?p=GSB")
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("td", {"class": "Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)",
                          "data-reactid": ".1ujetg16lcg.0.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.2.0.0.0.1.0.1:$FINANCIAL_HIGHLIGHTS.$BALANCE_SHEET.1.0.$CURRENT_RATIO.1"
                         })
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The data is rendered using react i.e Javascript so it is not in the source.

Comment: As @PadraicCunningham already pointed out the issue, an option is to scrape using something like selenium or selenium itself.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try to scrap it using selenium.

Comment: @Fxs7576 Where is your Selenium solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually get the data is json format, there is a call to an api that returns a lot of the data including the current ratio:

[image]

```
import requests

params = {"formatted": "true",
        "crumb": "AKV/cl0TOgz", # works without so not sure of significance
        "lang": "en-US",
        "region": "US",
        "modules": "defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents",
        "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com"}

r = requests.get("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/GSB", params=params)
data = r.json()[u'quoteSummary']["result"][0]
```

That gives you a dict with numerous pieces of data:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(data)
{u'calendarEvents': {u'dividendDate': {u'fmt': u'2016-09-08',
                                        u'raw': 1473292800},
                      u'earnings': {u'earningsAverage': {},
                                    u'earningsDate': [{u'fmt': u'2016-10-27',
                                                       u'raw': 1477526400}],
                                    u'earningsHigh': {},
                                    u'earningsLow': {},
                                    u'revenueAverage': {u'fmt': u'8.72M',
                                                        u'longFmt': u'8,720,000',
                                                        u'raw': 8720000},
                                    u'revenueHigh': {u'fmt': u'8.72M',
                                                     u'longFmt': u'8,720,000',
                                                     u'raw': 8720000},
                                    u'revenueLow': {u'fmt': u'8.72M',
                                                    u'longFmt': u'8,720,000',
                                                    u'raw': 8720000}},
                      u'exDividendDate': {u'fmt': u'2016-05-19',
                                          u'raw': 1463616000},
                      u'maxAge': 1},
  u'defaultKeyStatistics': {u'52WeekChange': {u'fmt': u'3.35%',
                                              u'raw': 0.033536673},
                            u'SandP52WeekChange': {u'fmt': u'5.21%',
                                                   u'raw': 0.052093267},
                            u'annualHoldingsTurnover': {},
                            u'annualReportExpenseRatio': {},
                            u'beta': {u'fmt': u'0.23', u'raw': 0.234153},
                            u'beta3Year': {},
                            u'bookValue': {u'fmt': u'1.29', u'raw': 1.295},
                            u'category': None,
                            u'earningsQuarterlyGrowth': {u'fmt': u'-28.00%',
                                                         u'raw': -0.28},
                            u'enterpriseToEbitda': {u'fmt': u'9.22',
                                                    u'raw': 9.215},
                            u'enterpriseToRevenue': {u'fmt': u'1.60',
                                                     u'raw': 1.596},
                            u'enterpriseValue': {u'fmt': u'50.69M',
                                                 u'longFmt': u'50,690,408',
                                                 u'raw': 50690408},
                            u'fiveYearAverageReturn': {},
                            u'floatShares': {u'fmt': u'11.63M',
                                             u'longFmt': u'11,628,487',
                                             u'raw': 11628487},
                            u'forwardEps': {u'fmt': u'0.29', u'raw': 0.29},
                            u'forwardPE': {},
                            u'fundFamily': None,
                            u'fundInceptionDate': {},
                            u'heldPercentInsiders': {u'fmt': u'36.12%',
                                                     u'raw': 0.36116},
                            u'heldPercentInstitutions': {u'fmt': u'21.70%',
                                                         u'raw': 0.21700001},
                            u'lastCapGain': {},
                            u'lastDividendValue': {},
                            u'lastFiscalYearEnd': {u'fmt': u'2015-12-31',
                                                   u'raw': 1451520000},
                            u'lastSplitDate': {},
                            u'lastSplitFactor': None,
                            u'legalType': None,
                            u'maxAge': 1,
                            u'morningStarOverallRating': {},
                            u'morningStarRiskRating': {},
                            u'mostRecentQuarter': {u'fmt': u'2016-06-30',
                                                   u'raw': 1467244800},
                            u'netIncomeToCommon': {u'fmt': u'3.82M',
                                                   u'longFmt': u'3,819,000',
                                                   u'raw': 3819000},
                            u'nextFiscalYearEnd': {u'fmt': u'2017-12-31',
                                                   u'raw': 1514678400},
                            u'pegRatio': {},
                            u'priceToBook': {u'fmt': u'2.64',
                                             u'raw': 2.6358302},
                            u'priceToSalesTrailing12Months': {},
                            u'profitMargins': {u'fmt': u'12.02%',
                                               u'raw': 0.12023},
                            u'revenueQuarterlyGrowth': {},
                            u'sharesOutstanding': {u'fmt': u'21.18M',
                                                   u'longFmt': u'21,184,300',
                                                   u'raw': 21184300},
                            u'sharesShort': {u'fmt': u'27.06k',
                                             u'longFmt': u'27,057',
                                             u'raw': 27057},
                            u'sharesShortPriorMonth': {u'fmt': u'36.35k',
                                                       u'longFmt': u'36,352',
                                                       u'raw': 36352},
                            u'shortPercentOfFloat': {u'fmt': u'0.20%',
                                                     u'raw': 0.001977},
                            u'shortRatio': {u'fmt': u'0.81', u'raw': 0.81},
                            u'threeYearAverageReturn': {},
                            u'totalAssets': {},
                            u'trailingEps': {u'fmt': u'0.18', u'raw': 0.18},
                            u'yield': {},
                            u'ytdReturn': {}},
  u'financialData': {u'currentPrice': {u'fmt': u'3.41', u'raw': 3.4134},
                     u'currentRatio': {u'fmt': u'1.97', u'raw': 1.974},
                     u'debtToEquity': {},
                     u'earningsGrowth': {u'fmt': u'-33.30%', u'raw': -0.333},
                     u'ebitda': {u'fmt': u'5.5M',
                                 u'longFmt': u'5,501,000',
                                 u'raw': 5501000},
                     u'ebitdaMargins': {u'fmt': u'17.32%',
                                        u'raw': 0.17318001},
                     u'freeCashflow': {u'fmt': u'4.06M',
                                       u'longFmt': u'4,062,250',
                                       u'raw': 4062250},
                     u'grossMargins': {u'fmt': u'79.29%', u'raw': 0.79288},
                     u'grossProfits': {u'fmt': u'25.17M',
                                       u'longFmt': u'25,172,000',
                                       u'raw': 25172000},
                     u'maxAge': 86400,
                     u'numberOfAnalystOpinions': {},
                     u'operatingCashflow': {u'fmt': u'6.85M',
                                            u'longFmt': u'6,853,000',
                                            u'raw': 6853000},
                     u'operatingMargins': {u'fmt': u'16.47%',
                                           u'raw': 0.16465001},
                     u'profitMargins': {u'fmt': u'12.02%', u'raw': 0.12023},
                     u'quickRatio': {u'fmt': u'1.92', u'raw': 1.917},
                     u'recommendationKey': u'strong_buy',
                     u'recommendationMean': {u'fmt': u'1.00', u'raw': 1.0},
                     u'returnOnAssets': {u'fmt': u'7.79%', u'raw': 0.07793},
                     u'returnOnEquity': {u'fmt': u'15.05%', u'raw': 0.15054},
                     u'revenueGrowth': {u'fmt': u'5.00%', u'raw': 0.05},
                     u'revenuePerShare': {u'fmt': u'1.51', u'raw': 1.513},
                     u'targetHighPrice': {},
                     u'targetLowPrice': {},
                     u'targetMeanPrice': {},
                     u'targetMedianPrice': {},
                     u'totalCash': {u'fmt': u'20.28M',
                                    u'longFmt': u'20,277,000',
                                    u'raw': 20277000},
                     u'totalCashPerShare': {u'fmt': u'0.96', u'raw': 0.957},
                     u'totalDebt': {u'fmt': None,
                                    u'longFmt': u'0',
                                    u'raw': 0},
                     u'totalRevenue': {u'fmt': u'31.76M',
                                       u'longFmt': u'31,764,000',
                                       u'raw': 31764000}}}
```

What you want is in `data[u'financialData']`:

```
 pp(data[u'financialData'])

 {u'currentPrice': {u'fmt': u'3.41', u'raw': 3.4134},
 u'currentRatio': {u'fmt': u'1.97', u'raw': 1.974},
 u'debtToEquity': {},
 u'earningsGrowth': {u'fmt': u'-33.30%', u'raw': -0.333},
 u'ebitda': {u'fmt': u'5.5M', u'longFmt': u'5,501,000', u'raw': 5501000},
 u'ebitdaMargins': {u'fmt': u'17.32%', u'raw': 0.17318001},
 u'freeCashflow': {u'fmt': u'4.06M',
                   u'longFmt': u'4,062,250',
                   u'raw': 4062250},
 u'grossMargins': {u'fmt': u'79.29%', u'raw': 0.79288},
 u'grossProfits': {u'fmt': u'25.17M',
                   u'longFmt': u'25,172,000',
                   u'raw': 25172000},
 u'maxAge': 86400,
 u'numberOfAnalystOpinions': {},
 u'operatingCashflow': {u'fmt': u'6.85M',
                        u'longFmt': u'6,853,000',
                        u'raw': 6853000},
 u'operatingMargins': {u'fmt': u'16.47%', u'raw': 0.16465001},
 u'profitMargins': {u'fmt': u'12.02%', u'raw': 0.12023},
 u'quickRatio': {u'fmt': u'1.92', u'raw': 1.917},
 u'recommendationKey': u'strong_buy',
 u'recommendationMean': {u'fmt': u'1.00', u'raw': 1.0},
 u'returnOnAssets': {u'fmt': u'7.79%', u'raw': 0.07793},
 u'returnOnEquity': {u'fmt': u'15.05%', u'raw': 0.15054},
 u'revenueGrowth': {u'fmt': u'5.00%', u'raw': 0.05},
 u'revenuePerShare': {u'fmt': u'1.51', u'raw': 1.513},
 u'targetHighPrice': {},
 u'targetLowPrice': {},
 u'targetMeanPrice': {},
 u'targetMedianPrice': {},
 u'totalCash': {u'fmt': u'20.28M',
                u'longFmt': u'20,277,000',
                u'raw': 20277000},
 u'totalCashPerShare': {u'fmt': u'0.96', u'raw': 0.957},
 u'totalDebt': {u'fmt': None, u'longFmt': u'0', u'raw': 0},
 u'totalRevenue': {u'fmt': u'31.76M',
                   u'longFmt': u'31,764,000',
                   u'raw': 31764000}}
```

You can see `u'currentRatio'` in there, the fmt is the formatted output you see on the site, formatted to two decimal places. So to get the 1.97:

```
In [5]: import requests
   ...: data = {"formatted": "true",
   ...:         "crumb": "AKV/cl0TOgz",
   ...:         "lang": "en-US",
   ...:         "region": "US",
   ...:         "modules": "defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents",
   ...:         "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com"}
   ...: r = requests.get("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSumm
   ...: ary/GSB", params=data)
   ...: data = r.json()[u'quoteSummary']["result"][0][u'financialData']
   ...: ratio = data[u'currentRatio']
   ...: print(ratio)
   ...: print(ratio["fmt"])
   ...: 
{'raw': 1.974, 'fmt': '1.97'}
1.97
```

The equivalent code using *urllib*:

```
In [1]: import urllib
   ...: from urllib import urlencode
   ...: from json import load
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: data = {"formatted": "true",
   ...:         "crumb": "AKV/cl0TOgz",
   ...:         "lang": "en-US",
   ...:         "region": "US",
   ...:         "modules": "defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents",
   ...:         "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com"}
   ...: url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/GSB"
   ...: r = urllib.urlopen(url, data=urlencode(data))
   ...: data = load(r)[u'quoteSummary']["result"][0][u'financialData']
   ...: ratio = data[u'currentRatio']
   ...: print(ratio)
   ...: print(ratio["fmt"])
   ...: 
{u'raw': 1.974, u'fmt': u'1.97'}
1.97
```

It works fine for APPL also:

```
In [1]: import urllib
   ...: from urllib import urlencode
   ...: from json import load
   ...: data = {"formatted": "true",
   ...:         "lang": "en-US",
   ...:         "region": "US",
   ...:         "modules": "defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents",
   ...:         "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com"}
   ...: url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL"
   ...: r = urllib.urlopen(url, data=urlencode(data))
   ...: data = load(r)[u'quoteSummary']["result"][0][u'financialData']
   ...: ratio = data[u'currentRatio']
   ...: print(ratio)
   ...: print(ratio["fmt"])
   ...: 
{u'raw': 1.312, u'fmt': u'1.31'}
1.31
```

Adding the crumb parameters seems to have no effect, if you need to get it at a later date:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GSB/key-statistics?p=GSB").read())
script = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("root.App.main")).text
data = loads(re.search("root.App.main\s+=\s+(\{.*\})", script).group(1))
print(data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["CrumbStore"]["crumb"])
```

For market cap, you need to add the *summaryDetail* module:

```
In [1]: import requests
   ...: 
   ...: params = {"formatted": "true",
   ...:           "crumb": "AKV/cl0TOgz",  # works without so not sure of signif
   ...: icance
   ...:           "lang": "en-US",
   ...:           "region": "US",
   ...:           "modules": "summaryDetail",
   ...:           "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com"}
   ...: 
   ...: r = requests.get("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSumm
   ...: ary/GOOG", params=params)
   ...: data = r.json()[u'quoteSummary']["result"][0]
   ...: print(data["summaryDetail"]["marketCap"])
   ...: 
{'raw': 769972436992, 'fmt': '769.97B', 'longFmt': '769,972,436,992'}
```

The available modules I know of are:

```
defaultKeyStatistics
financialData
calendarEvents
assetProfile
summaryDetail
upgradeDowngradeHistory
recommendationTrend
earnings
price
```

Comment: What do the headers do here? Whats the difference between that and going straight to the `GET` url given?

Comment: @RafaelMartins, they are params for the get request, you can add whatever you like and either requests/urlencode will handle any encoding.

Comment: @Padraic: It works like a charm. However, what is the purpose of the dictionary called params/data here?

Comment: @Fxs7576, sorry I should have used params everywhere to be consistent, they are the  params for the get request, not all are necessary and you can probably influence the output by playing around with them but I will leave that up to you  to discover ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How do you get the market capitalization using this method? Thanks.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen, I added a snippet at the bottom with what you need,

Answer (score 3):

One thing I'd add to Padriac's answer is to except KeyErrors, since you'll probably be scraping more than one ticker.

```
import requests
a = requests.get('https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/GSB?formatted=true&crumb=A7e5%2FXKKAFa&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=defaultKeyStatistics%2CfinancialData%2CcalendarEvents&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com')
b = a.json()
try:
    ratio = b['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['financialData']['currentRatio']['raw']
    print(ratio) #prints 1.974
except (IndexError, KeyError):
    pass
```

A cool thing about doing it like this is that you can easily change the keys for the information you want.  A good way to see the way the dictionary is nested on the Yahoo! Finance pages is to use `pprint`. Furthermore, for the pages that have quarterly information just change `[0]` to `[1]` to get the info for the second quarter instead of the first.. and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution which uses Excel.

http://www.financialwisdomforum.org/gummy-stuff/Yahoo-data.htm

[image]

[image]

Download a sample workbook from one of the many links on that site.  That will do everything you want, and a whole lot more.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is not the answer you are looking for, but R can do this very easily and very quickly.  See the link below.

http://allthingsr.blogspot.com/2012/10/pull-yahoo-finance-key-statistics.html

```
#######################################################################
# Script to download key metrics for a set of stock tickers using the quantmod package
#######################################################################
require(quantmod)
require("plyr")
what_metrics <- yahooQF(c("Price/Sales", 
                          "P/E Ratio",
                          "Price/EPS Estimate Next Year",
                          "PEG Ratio",
                          "Dividend Yield", 
                          "Market Capitalization"))

tickers <- c("AAPL", "FB", "GOOG", "HPQ", "IBM", "MSFT", "ORCL", "SAP")
# Not all the metrics are returned by Yahoo.
metrics <- getQuote(paste(tickers, sep="", collapse=";"), what=what_metrics)

#Add tickers as the first column and remove the first column which had date stamps
metrics <- data.frame(Symbol=tickers, metrics[,2:length(metrics)]) 

#Change colnames
colnames(metrics) <- c("Symbol", "Revenue Multiple", "Earnings Multiple", 
                       "Earnings Multiple (Forward)", "Price-to-Earnings-Growth", "Div Yield", "Market Cap")

#Persist this to the csv file
write.csv(metrics, "FinancialMetrics.csv", row.names=FALSE)

#######################################################################

#######################################################################
##Alternate method to download all key stats using XML and x_path - PREFERRED WAY
#######################################################################

setwd("C:/Users/i827456/Pictures/Blog/Oct-25")
require(XML)
require(plyr)
getKeyStats_xpath <- function(symbol) {
  yahoo.URL <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="
  html_text <- htmlParse(paste(yahoo.URL, symbol, sep = ""), encoding="UTF-8")

  #search for <td> nodes anywhere that have class 'yfnc_tablehead1'
  nodes <- getNodeSet(html_text, "/*//td[@class='yfnc_tablehead1']")

  if(length(nodes) > 0 ) {
   measures <- sapply(nodes, xmlValue)

   #Clean up the column name
   measures <- gsub(" *[0-9]*:", "", gsub(" \\(.*?\\)[0-9]*:","", measures))   

   #Remove dups
   dups <- which(duplicated(measures))
   #print(dups) 
   for(i in 1:length(dups)) 
     measures[dups[i]] = paste(measures[dups[i]], i, sep=" ")

   #use siblings function to get value
   values <- sapply(nodes, function(x)  xmlValue(getSibling(x)))

   df <- data.frame(t(values))
   colnames(df) <- measures
   return(df)
  } else {
    break
  }
}

tickers <- c("AAPL")
stats <- ldply(tickers, getKeyStats_xpath)
rownames(stats) <- tickers
write.csv(t(stats), "FinancialStats_updated.csv",row.names=TRUE)  

#######################################################################
```

[image]